# app.js:5Uncaught [DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase

please how can i solve this? Uncaught [DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).V.hasOwnProperty.Object.defineProperty.value @ polyfills.js:3e @ app.js:5t.ErrorFactory.o.value @ app.js:5o @ app.js:5e @ app.js:5u @ app.js:5(anonymous function) @ app.component.ts:11__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap ec8f9a1…:47(anonymous function) @ src async:38__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap ec8f9a1…:47(anonymous function) @ setImmediate.js:186__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap ec8f9a1…:47(anonymous function) @ bootstrap ec8f9a1…:139(anonymous function) @ bootstrap ec8f9a1…:139
ion-dev.js?v=1.3.7:138 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.window.IonicDevServer.drainMessageQueue @ ion-dev.js?v=1.3.7:138window.IonicDevServer.queueMessageSend @ ion-dev.js?v=1.3.7:130window.IonicDevServer.handleError @ ion-dev.js?v=1.3.7:61window.onerror @ ion-dev.js?v=1.3.7:41
polyfills.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuVGQ.png)

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "MyEventManager",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.1.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {}
    }
  }
}
```

```js
app.component.ts

import { Component, NgZone  } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import  firebase  from 'firebase';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any;
  zone:NgZone;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, zone:NgZone) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });

    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCWRv_TtIrZItQTqPTXR1Rm5QQYy7NNE8c",
      authDomain: "geoentreprise.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://geoentreprise.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "geoentreprise.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "653212172629"
    });
    //initialize the default app
   /* var defaultApp = admin.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);
    console.log(defaultApp.name);
    //retrieve services via the defaultApp variable...
    var defaultAuth=defaultAuth.auth();
    var defaultDatabase = defaultApp.database();
    //or use the equivalent shorthand notation
    defaultAuth = admin.auth();
    defaultDatabase = admin.dabase();*/

    this.zone = new NgZone({});
  }


}

const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  this.zone.run( () => {
    if (!user) {
      this.rootPage = 'login';
      unsubscribe();
    } else {
      this.rootPage = HomePage;
      unsubscribe();
    }
  });
});
```

```js
app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { AuthProvider } from '../providers/auth/auth';
import { EventProvider } from '../providers/event/event';
import { ProfileProvider } from '../providers/profile/profile';

class CameraMock  {
  getPicture(options){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(`TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCBieSB0aGlzIHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2YgdGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2Ugb2YgZGVsaWdodCBpbiB0aGUgY29udGludWVkIGFuZCBpbmRlZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gb2Yga25vd2xlZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRoZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=`);
    });
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    AuthProvider,
    EventProvider,
    ProfileProvider,
    {provide: Camera, useClass: CameraMock}
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Try `import * as firebase from "firebase";`